# XML to HTML: Stop loop after a certain number of rows

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing

I have a quick question regarding XML to HTML looping. I followed the [w3schools guideline](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp) to render a HTML table from an XML document and everything works great! I don't want to change anything about the code, but I was wondering if it was possible to stop the loop after, say, ten rows have been rendered even if the original XML file contains more data. If so, how would I alter the code from the example shown by w3schools (reproduced below)?

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Break statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

The for loop is counting and writing lines from 0 (i=0) to number of XML rows(x.length)... Just make it run from 0 to 9 .. then you got 10 lines
You could do it by 2 ways:

1st:
replace

```
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
```

with

```
for (i=0;i<=9;i++)
```

2nd:

Including an if statement inside for brackets

```
    <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  if(i==10)
     break;
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you! That seems to have done the trick to perfection!